# Convert .qml to .lyr

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, symbology, layer-file

I am working on a project with two different teams, each working with a different GIS software package: QGIS and ArcGIS. I am trying to convert my QGIS layout to ArcGIS, so the team with ArcGIS can see exactly the same symbology as I do on my computer.

I am currently working with .qml files to save my layer styling, and I would like the other team to be able to visualize the same symbology for the layers we're both using. So I want to **convert all my layer symbologies from .qml to .lyr.**

Is it possible for them to use the .qml format in ArcGIS?

Is there a way to make all projects have the same symbols, without having to exchange RGB values, point style, line style, etc, etc...?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify what have you tried so far. You'll likely need to provide yourself with a gerous definition of success, since the odds of achieving an ***exact*** match seems unlikely.

Comment: Your title says `.qsl` while your question body says `.qml`.  Which are you wanting to try and convert to layer files?  Are you asking how to do this from ArcGIS Desktop, or from QGIS?

Comment: Please let me know if the problem is better explained now. I can give you more informations if necessary. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you every solve this problem? I have the same challenge and would really appreciate any solution that you came up with. Tx

Comment: No, sorry. I don´t think that this is possible to accomplish.